# What's a good iTunes alternative to use with my iPod nano 6g?

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, ipod, ipod-nano

I'm looking for an iTunes alternative for my new iPod nano 6g.

I've used sharepod before but it doesn't work with the nano 6g—I can upload songs but they're not being recognized by the iPod database.

Any ideas on alternatives that work with the nano 6g?

Comment: Even though the list on media monkey says it works, if you dig deeper it works for 6G classic and up to 5G Nano.  No 6G nano.  sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Mediamonkey is a good alternative on Windows, the nano 6th gen is present in the [list of compatible devices](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Compatible_Devices).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Windows, try [DoubleTwist](http://www.doubletwist.com/). (Not sure if it supports Apple products on OS X yet.)

Comment: looks like it works only for android devices?